# How to format Time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following function, where within a `ListBody` I map List values, I have a time parameter that returns a time. This contains unnecessary digits and I want to format it.

In other normal `List` situations I use the function

```
    var timeFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm");
    String timetest = timeFormat.format(my_data);
```

How can I implement my above function to format the time in the below RichText, where I enter data into TextSpan from the map, and cannot build it as a `var` outside and then call it in?

```
var mappedValues = ListBody(
    children: [...mappedList.map((m) => RichText (
       text: TextSpan( 
              children: <TextSpan> [
       
              TextSpan(text: m.time!.toLocal().toString(), style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18 ,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, 
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontFamily: 'DMSans'
               )
              ),
            ]
    )))]);
```

Thank you

**Update**

Example of initial output

```
    2022-03-05 23:24:00.000
```

My function will turn it to

```
    23:24
```

Comment: You should be able to create a separate function that takes the time as input and returns to you the formatted string to be placed inside the TextSpan. Can you show what you’re getting out of the m.time! ?

Comment: Have added update, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should be able to create a method within this widget that takes the **Datetime** (m.time) as input and returns the formatted time, as:

```dart
String getFormattedTime(DateTime time) {

 var timeFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm");
 String timePortion = timeFormat.format(time);
 return timePortion;
}
```

Then inside your widget just call it:

```dart
TextSpan(text: getFormattedTime(m.time!))
```

You could also move this method into a common utility class so you can reuse it throughout your app. Let me know if that’s what you looking for and works for your purposes.

Check out this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/c9ae894bab1d024a77f26ddb24a05ca4) (make sure to run it through DartPad) that I created that illustrates my point. Another suggestion would be to use **ListView** in favor or **ListBody** as it is more robust.

You should get output that looks like this:

[image]

Let me know if that's clear.

Comment: I need to be able to map the List as in line ```children: [...mappedList.map((m) => RichText (```. ```my_data``` has to be ```m.time!``` which will only work in the ```mappedList.map((m) =>``` body

Comment: My mistake. I should've passed **time** inside **timeFormat.format()** like **timeFormat.format(time)**. Yes you can do any of those things you're saying, no problem. I updated my answer.